# Calculating the variance of a rate

Tags: variance, inference, standard-error

It is easy to show that to calculate the variance of a sample mean, you can derive: $var(\overline{x}) = \sigma^2/n$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of x.

What about if x is a rate? say it is a fertility rate, so $x=(\frac{number\ of \ live\  births}{number\ of\ women})$

Is now the denomenator not 'fixed' but also subject to sampling variability?

Comment: Whatever it is, $\operatorname{var}(\bar x)$ will be the same. Can you explain a bit more about what you want to calculate?

Comment: If x as a variable is a rate- so the number of livebirths/number of women in the sample, or any other rate where you are dividing a count by a count of a relevant scaling population, I was trying to calculate what the variance is in the same way you can calculate the variance of the mean

Comment: Let's say $x$ is a rate, meaning, $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are iid rates. The formula would be the same. If you try to describe a dependence between $x_i$ and $x_j$, could you please describe it more explicitly (and mathematically)?